# Is it ok to use present tense "don't" in this sentence "I enjoyed all my previous jobs but I don't seem to find satisfaction."?

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense, modal-verbs, sentence-structure

I'm trying to say something like "I can't seem to find satisfaction" but it sounds wrong. I can't just put it like "I didn't find satisfaction" because I don't mean it that way because up til now I have yet to find satisfaction.

Comment: What about "I'm not satistified." Would that work? More context would help.

Answer (score 1):

> I *didn't find* any satisfaction in those jobs.  <sup>past</sup>

When I held those jobs, they were not satisfactory.

> I *haven't found* any satisfaction in the jobs I've held.  <sup>present perfect</sup>

*So far*, no job that I've ever held has been satisfactory.

> I *don't find* any satisfaction in that kind of job.  <sup>present</sup>

I do not like that kind of job.  Such jobs are not for me.

*The present can be used to describe a general state of affairs.*

> I *can't seem* to find satisfaction in such jobs.  <sup>present</sup>

Identical to "I don't find" in terms of the time reference, but not as certain a statement.  Something about yourself, or about those jobs, makes the experience unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about previous jobs as past events and the fact that you didn't find satisfaction in them.  "I didn't find satisfaction" means exactly that--up until now you have yet to find satisfaction.  So that sentence would work fine.

You can also look at the situation from a slightly different perspective.  Instead of sitting here today looking back at the past, you can characterize the ongoing process of moving through time from one job to the next, not finding satisfaction at each one in turn, and continuing to the present time.  That would be the sentence in the title, “I enjoyed all my previous jobs but I don't seem to find satisfaction.”

I think "have enjoyed" would be more consistent with a continuing process.  Also, you could tie the satisfaction more explicitly to the jobs:

> I have enjoyed all my previous jobs but I don't seem to find satisfaction in them.

"Don't" implies that you are still in that situation and see the pattern somewhat as a characteristic of yourself.  A variation would be:

> I have enjoyed all my previous jobs but I haven't found satisfaction in them.

That is similar but implies that although that was the past pattern, you anticipate that it could change.  You just haven't found the right job, yet.

Of course if you are a Rolling Stone, you could say, "I can't get no satisfaction."  :-)

Comment: Thanks, fixer1234! What about this one?  "I already had previous jobs and I must say I enjoyed it all but I don't seem to find satisfaction." Is it correct?

Comment: "haven't seemed to find" is not correct: you use **do** rather than **have** when you use a stative verb like **seem**. "didn't seem to find" or "haven't found" would be OK. And the Rolling Stones song is called "I can't get no satisfaction".

Comment: @JavaLatte Thank you! What do you think of the sentence I wrote above your comment? Is it acceptable?

Comment: @RomaA, there are an infinite number of variations on possible ways to say this.  The most useful way to understand what makes them correct/incorrect or good is to focus on the principles rather than the words.  What are you trying to accomplish different in the sentence in your comment?

Comment: @fixer1234 I'm not sure if I'm making any sense. But do the phrases preceding "don't seem to..." makes the usage of "don't" grammatically acceptable or is it completely wrong?

Comment: @RomaA, aside from a minor nit (use "them all" instead of "it all"), the sentence in your comment is effectively the same as the one in the title in terms of how the first half relates to the last half.  So my input in the answer would similarly apply to it.  It could be polished a little to sound more idiomatic, but the them vs. it is the only thing not grammatically acceptable.  However, the first part is past tense and "don't" is present tense, so the two halves seem almost unrelated, like you're combining two unrelated thoughts in one sentence.  (cont'd)

Comment: To tie the jobs and the satisfaction together, the tenses need to be more consistent.  I'm about to shut down, but feel free to leave additional comments and I'll get back to you later in the day.